# how to differentiate the site created using MS Teams and site created using SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-teams

I want to differentiate that how many sites are created using MS Teams and how many sites are created using SharePoint?

Comment: Please describe your problem more clearly, what do you mean about using MS Teams and using SharePoint?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to be able to tell the difference between SP sites made using different methods? There's no essential difference: both are Office 365 Groups.

Comment: I mean, In the sharepoint admin center i will get a list of all the sites created but i want to filter out that which sites are created using Microsoft Teams?

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to get those sites that are not connected to MS teams. If so, you can use below filter view:

[image]

You can check if a site has a connected group/teams programmatically via their web property "group id":

```
_api/web?$select=AllProperties&$expand=AllProperties
```

[image]

BR